# Character is entering the ground when making an attack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I am developing a game with unity and I am having the following problem, when the enemy character will make an attack he is entering the ground, it only happens when he will attack. Already added a rigibody and a capsule collider and this problem persisite. 
The floor is with a Box Collider.

Link to object inspector images (character)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbg31.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj6pB.png

Walking Character:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNXNM.png

Attacking Character:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSFcp.png

One detail when he attacks him comes out of the Capsule Colider's frame.
Capsule Colider when character is stopped: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkWLj.png
Capsule Colider when character is attacking: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdAcW.png

Comment: Could you please provide some of the code where you are managing your animations?

Comment: Hey Braden, Thanks for offering help but I managed to solve it using Kaynn's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue is with the pivot point of each of the sprite.

When the sprite renderer changes the current sprite that it renders, the 'center point' of where the new sprite will be rendered at depends on each of the sprite's pivot point.

Ensure that the pivot point for each of the sprite for that specific character is set to a common place.
(For your case, you can try to set the pivot point to the neck/head of the character; Since it is unlikely that you are going to rotate the character.)

Note the changing the pivot point would also change the point which the character would rotate at.